# How to give a Component as a parameter to the react-router in an application start

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When the URL http://server:port/ (and index.html) is loaded with the following react-router configuration

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Component1}/>
      <Route path="/component1" component={Component1}/>
      <Route path="/component2" component={Component2}/>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

the component Component1 is run. How to change the router so that we can run dynamically Component1 or Component2 when the Javascript application is first time started? Is that possible?

So if we load the URL something like this

```
http://server:port/component1
```

the Component1 is run and if we load the URL something like this

```
http://server:port/component2
```

the Component2 is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works when I added forward from Spring boot from different URL:s ("/component1", "/component2") to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using `Plain route` -

Route

```
export default (store) => ({
path : 'songs',
getComponent (nextState, cb) {
  require.ensure([], (require) => {
     //get component 
     cb(null, component)
  }, 'webpack-bundle')
}
```

Your router jsx

```
const routes = require('./routes/index').default(store)
<Router history={browserHistory} children={routes} />
```

And routes object its

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path        : '/',
  component   : //layout,
  indexRoute  : //index route,
  childRoutes : [//all routes of appliction]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not easy to understand. Is it working in my situation? When the browser loads the URL http://server:port/, first is loaded http://server:port/index.html. The index.html has the reference to the javascript file. If the browser loads first (without loading javascript file) http://server:port/component1, it tries to load http://server:port/component1/index.html, but there will be error because there are not index.html in that server folder.

Comment: Browser will be referenced to the indexRoute, indexRoute will referenceto the such as `songs` route in answer - in method, where you will return any  component as you want